# Adding padding between cells in a video gallery

Tags: html

I'm trying to add padding between the videos in the following code. Any pointers or tips?:

```html
<table width="100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
    <div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;"><iframe style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SxK8XBnYZRk?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="300" height="150" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Battle of Whitehall by <a href="http://www.rockinpaddy.com/">Rockinpaddy</a>, London</p>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
    <div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;"><iframe style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uS0-xSoxH1o?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="300" height="150" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Which Side Are You On by <a href="http://www.rockinpaddy.com/">Rockinpaddy</a>, London</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by padding in between the videos?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Use tables for tabular data. Kinda been the mantra since the late 90's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting some padding on the `td` element like this:

```css
td {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
<div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;"><iframe style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SxK8XBnYZRk?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="300" height="150" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
<p style="text-align: center;">Battle of Whitehall by <a href="http://www.rockinpaddy.com/">Rockinpaddy</a>, London</p>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
<div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;"><iframe style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uS0-xSoxH1o?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="300" height="150" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
<p style="text-align: center;">Which Side Are You On by <a href="http://www.rockinpaddy.com/">Rockinpaddy</a>, London</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi,

Looks to work in the snippet - thanks! Can you clarify where this td element code goes? It appears just as text when I place it directly before the <table>. Does it belong in <td>? Thank you and sorry for my lack of knowledge.